# join a table in two columns due to polymorphic relation

Tags: join, laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphism

I have the following structure:

**Buro->hasOne->Address->hasOne->City->hasOne->State
Buro->hasOne->Category**

and

**Order->hasOne->Address->hasOne->City->hasOne->State
Order->hasOne->Category**

and

**Category->hasMany->Orders and Category->hasMany->Buros**

I have a "One-To-Many" polymorphic relation between addresses in one side and Buro/Orders in the other side. There is just One address for a buro and just one adddress for an order, therefor I couls use [0] to get the first the first and only one element in a collection.

**Address class**

```php
class Address extends Model
{
...

    public function addressable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
...
}
```

**Büro class**

```php
class Buro extends Model
{
....
    public function addressable()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Address', 'addressable');
    }
...
}
```

**Order class**

```php
class order extends Model
{
....
    public function addressable()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Address', 'addressable');
    }
...
}
```

Now I am building a form in the frontend with a SELECT field in order to select just from the Buros that operate in the same State where the order was placed.

Using ELOQUENT I did this:

```php
$all_bueros = Buero::where('category_id', $order->category_id)
                    ->where('title', $order->client->addressable[0]->city->state->title) // <- Look at this "title" column name
                    ->pluck('title', 'id')->all();
```

The problem here is that the **"Title"** column name is  not in **"Buros"** table but three tables away. Exactly in: **buros.addresses.city.state.title**

I have tried these syntaxes but no one worked:

```php
->where('buros.addresses.city.state.title', $order->client->addressable[0]->city->state->title)   // as object notation
```

and

```php
->where('buros->addressable[0]->cities->state->title', $order->client->addressable[0]->city->state->title)  // using the relation
```

I used the query builder but there is even more messy:

```php
$buros = DB::table('buros')
                    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', $order->category_id)
                    ->join('addresses', 'addresses.addressable_id', '=', $order->id, 'AND','addresses', 'addresses.addressable_type', '=', 'buros') //two points to join the table
                    ->join('cities', 'addresses.city_id', '=', 'cities.id')
                    ->join('states', 'cities.states', '=', 'states.id')
                    ->select('buros.title', 'buros.id')
                    ->where('states.title', '=', $order->client->addressable[0]->city->states->title)
                    ->get();
```

My problem is how to join a table in two points since there is a polymorphic relation. Because I need to join the Address Table in the "Buro-column" (addressable_type) and in the Buro-id column (addressable_id)

Any help will be appretiate

Comment: Are you sure you really need polymorphic relations ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid If I use just one table to store addresses from buros and orders I do not think I have another option. In the future I will need to expand this addresses table to also store profiles from addreses. Therefore, making more than one table to store addresses is not a good option

Comment: *"There is just One address for a buro and just one address for an order"*: Can't you convert `HasOne` into `BelongsTo`? `buro.address_id`, `order.address_id`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, Actually, the relation between Buro/Order and Address is Polymorphic. buro.addressable, order.addressable. What I meant is that Physically each Buro has one address and one Order could be placed rom one place, so it has just one address. That means I can access each address without foreach, just adding the first instance of the Collection by [0]. I need the Polymorphism because the address could be from a buro or from an Order (addressable_type)

Comment: I think the relationship doesn't have to be polymorphic if you reverse it.

Comment: @RafaelMunoz I now got the idea to have a polymorphic relation, If you are having difficulty to match with tile which is under nested relations you could use `whereHas` filter like `whereHas('buros.addresses.city.state', function ($query) use($title) {    $query->where('title', 'like',$title); })` , I hope this helps

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir You are right. That is an easier way to do that. Thanks!